# Dialog Box not getting closed on clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am displaying a dialog box on opening of the page. But the problem is when I click on one of the buttons of dialog box, the dialog box window does not close. I don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x=$('#loginstatus').val();
    if(x==1){
        $("#dialog").html("Do You Want to go for Face Recognition and Detection?");
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            title: "Permission for Face Recognition",
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: { 
                "Yes,Why Not": function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                     callback("1");
                 },
                 "No,Thanx": function() {
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                     callback("2");
                 }
            }
       });
    }
});
```

And in html I have the dialog div and other necessary inputs.

**Html**:

```
<div name="dialog" id="dialog"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="loginstatus" id="loginstatus" value="<%=firstlogin%>"/>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @Cedric I added html part also

Comment: your code works.  jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BZH73/1/

Answer (score 0):

test this, I made some changes in button :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    var x=$('#loginstatus').val();
                    if(x==1){
                        $("#dialog").html("Do You Want to go for Face Recognition and Detection?");
                        $("#dialog").dialog({
                            autoOpen: true,
                            modal: true,
                            title: "Permission for Face Recognition",
                            width: 600,
                            height: 300,
                            resizable: false,
                            buttons: { 

                                "Yes,Why Not": function() {
                                callback("1");
                                $(this).dialog("close");


                            },
                            Cancel: function() {
                            callback("2");
                            $(this).dialog("close");

                            }

                            }

                    });
                    }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#dialog").dialog('close');
```

instead of

```
$(this).dialog("close");
```

It's not quite recommended to use `this` unless you are absolutely sure about the scope.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#dialog').click(function() {
$('.dialog').hide();
});
```

Comment: Wrap it in `<script>...</script>` tags and put it just before `</body>`